Cannot access array data in handlebars
I am having difficulty rendering data into handlebars. I have tried both {{#each}} and {{if}} processes in the view as follows:
{{#each obj}}
{{title}}
{{/each}}

The (abbreviated) json response is as follows, of which I am trying to access the title, date and content of each item in the array:
{
  "content": [
    {
      "title": "Meta Platforms Inc (NASDAQ: META) Stock Analysis: Recovery After Surprise Drop",
      "date": "2024-05-05 04:01:18",
      "content": "<h1>Meta Platforms Inc (NASDAQ: META) Stock Analysis: A Surprising Turn and Recovery</h1>\r\n<p>On April 25th, <a href=\"https://site.financialmodelingprep.com/financial-summary/META\">Meta Platforms Inc (NASDAQ: META)</a> experienced a surprising <strong>14%</strong> drop in stock price at the market open, despite reporting first-quarter earnings that exceeded expectations. The company announced earnings of <strong>$4.71</strong> per share, surpassing the forecasted <strong>$4.32</strong>. Following this initial decline, Meta's stock managed to rebound by more than <strong>8%</strong>. Despite the positive earnings report, the stock's unexpected drop puzzled investors but also indicated a potential hidden opportunity as it began to recover.</p>\r\n<p>The initial shock to Meta's stock price, despite outperforming earnings expectations, reflects the complex dynamics of investor sentiment and market reactions. However, the swift recovery and subsequent stability above the <strong>$400</strong> mark, particularly with the stock finding support at <strong>$414</strong>, underscore a strong investor confidence in Meta's fundamentals and future prospects. This resilience is further evidenced by the stock's performance, with a notable increase of <strong>$10.28</strong>, or approximately <strong>2.33%</strong>, trading at <strong>$451.96</strong>.",
      "tickers": "NASDAQ:META",
      "image": "https://portal.financialmodelingprep.com/positions/66373e5a2712335b9eeccbc4.jpeg",
      "link": "https://financialmodelingprep.com/market-news/meta-platforms-nasdaq-meta-stock-analysis-recovery",
      "author": "Tony Dante",
      "site": "Financial Modeling Prep"
    },

The request rendering the news view is as follows:
router.get('/news', function(req, res) {
  var url = 'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/fmp/articles?page=0&size=5&apikey=apikey'

  request(url, function (error, response, results) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      fs.writeFile('data/news/news.json', results, function (err) {
        //console.log(results)
        var obj = JSON.parse(results);
        console.log(obj)
        console.log("The file was saved as news.json");
      res.render('news', {obj})
        //res.render('news', { obj });
        if (err) {

          return console.log(err);
        }

      });

    }

  });
})



Please stop opening new questions with slight variations on a single problem.

From what you have shown, your template would need to be {{#each obj.content}}.

In Handlebars, the process of looping through an array or collection is called an "each" block. So, in the provided code snippet, {{#each articles}} initiates an "each" block, where articles is the array being iterated over. Within this block, each iteration represents one item from the articles array, and the content within the block is processed for each item in the array.
    {{#each articles}}
        <div>
            <h2>{{title}}</h2>
            <p>Date: {{date}}</p>
            <p>{{{content}}}</p>
            <p>Author: {{author}}</p>
            <p>Site: {{site}}</p>
            <a href="{{link}}">Read More</a>
            <img src="{{image}}" alt="{{title}}">
        </div>
        <hr>
    {{/each}}

This code sets up a web server using Express.js to render a news page. It fetches the latest news articles from a financial API using Axios.
Then, it renders the retrieved articles dynamically using a Handlebars template.
Finally, it listens for incoming requests on port 3000, allowing users to access the news page via a web browser.
Demo Code
 app.js

 views/news.hbs

app.js
import express from 'express';
import exphbs from 'express-handlebars';
import path from 'path';
import axios from 'axios';

const app = express();

const __dirname = path.dirname(new URL(import.meta.url).pathname);

// Configure Handlebars engine
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs.engine({
    extname: '.hbs',
    defaultLayout: false,
    layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views/layouts')
}));

app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
app.set('views, __dirname + ./views');

// Define route to fetch news articles from API
app.get('/news', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // Make GET request to the API endpoint
        const response = await axios.get('https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/fmp/articles?page=0&size=5&apikey={your API Key}');
        
        const articles = response.data.content; // Extract relevant data from the response
        
        // Render the 'news.hbs' view and pass the articles data
        res.render('news', { articles });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        res.status(500).send('An error occurred while fetching data.');
    }
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000; // Start the server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});

Note: replace with {your API Key}
./views/news.hbs
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>News</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Latest News</h1>
    {{#each articles}}
        <div>
            <h2>{{title}}</h2>
            <p>Date: {{date}}</p>
            <p>{{{content}}}</p> <!-- Use triple curly braces to render HTML content -->
            <p>Author: {{author}}</p>
            <p>Site: {{site}}</p>
            <a href="{{link}}">Read More</a>
            <img src="{{image}}" alt="{{title}}">
        </div>
        <hr>
    {{/each}}
</body>
</html>

Install dependencies
npm install express express-handlebars path axios

Run it
node app.js

Open it
By Browser
http://localhost:3000/news

Result

